Inexpressibility of properties with And, Implies, There Exists
I have been trying my hand at a sort of programming language that would allow connecting propositions via AND, IMPLIES, as well as abstraction via THERE EXISTS. But it looks like some basic mathematical concepts cannot be expressed with just these three connectives. What's odd is that this seems to be only a small portion of properties.
For example, a relation R over a set X being strongly connected is defined as: (there exist x, y in X) implies (xRy or yRx). However, I've been unable to express this using only AND and IMPLIES. I thought that was just me not being able to figure it out, but it looks like you cannot produce OR from just these without NOT.
I know AND and IMPLIES cannot express all of propositional logic, but I would like to know if there is some sort of fundamental distinction between "the mathematics you can do with AND and IMPLIES" and the mathematics you can do with other sets of connectives, as it looks like you can get pretty far with just AND and IMPLIES.

As a retired professional programmer, I see the stumbling block as determining whether $~x \in X,~$ where $~X~$ is defined in one of two ways: either by [Option-1] :  a finite set, such as $~X = {x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_n },~$ or by [Option-2] : $~x \in X \iff x ~$ satisfies certain properties.  An example would be if $~X = [1,4],~$ then you would need $~x \geq 1~$ and $~x \leq 4.~$ ...see next comment

Re the previous comment, as I see it, Option-2 doesn't really present a problem.  With Option-1, the only way that I know to handle it, is to create an array $~A = [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]~$ and then create code that (pseudocoded) is a loop : for $~i = 0, i < n~$ loop through $~A[i].~$ If $~x = A[i]~$ then $~x~$ has been found in $~X,~$ and you can abort the search.  If the search (i.e. loop) is never aborted, then $~x \not\in X.$

There's an entire theory about what sets of connectives are enough. See this Wikipedia article and this Wikipedia article.

user2661923, I should definitely think about that when it comes to implementation but for the time being I just want to focus on what can be done if we have a notion of set membership implemented.
David, the question is about the properties of the mathematics one can do with an incomplete set of connectives.

The second Wikipedia article I linked to, on Post’s lattice, is a full description of all possible sets of connectives and their strengths, not just about what sets of connectives are sufficient to express all Boolean functions. This is also studied in universal algebra as clones on the two element set. You might also be interested in this post.

(You can find plenty of descriptions as to what Boolean functions can be constructed using certain sets of connectives. Say, in your example, AND and IMPLIES generate the clone $P_1$, as you can find in the Wikipedia article. $P_1$ consists of all Boolean functions which output TRUE whenever all inputs are TRUE.)

I see, that sounds like a satisfactory answer. I did spend quite a few days going over those Wikipedia articles before asking but I guess I never put it that clearly.
